Property taxes paid on inherited property title in probate
My niece inherited a home from her father 3 years ago. The property has been in probate for over a year. My niece has paid the the taxes each of the 3 years. Can she deduct the taxes on her income tax return? She lives in Utah

Best advice I have is to talk to an accountant and or lawyer who has experience with this. Location and other details may change the answer.

Are the taxes enough to trigger itemization, or does she already itemize?  If the answer to that is "no" then its a moot point.

I am confused about the time frame, if it has been in probate why hasn't the estate been paying the taxes?

@mhoran_psprep: Good question. This is something the executor should have been taking care of.

Or the niece is the executor, but not clear on distinguishing actions as executor and as inheritor.

Or maybe there was nothing else in the estate but the house? Voting to close as unclear. Is it a primary residence for a niece? A rental property? How was the father using it? How was the estate using it? How is the niece using it?

Well, I'm about to pay property taxes on my parent's house which is part of their estate. As an executor, and trustee of the estate trust, I will write a check for the property taxes on the estate's checking account.

What's clear is you can't deduct property taxes you pay on a property you don't own. What's not clear is whether your neice actually owns the property or whether she should itemize deductions.
